# Angular form of components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm desperate in trying to find a solution.
Here is my profile page structure:

```
private formSections: any[] = [
{title: 'General information',     name: 'general'},
{title: 'Financial Information',   name: 'financial'},
{title: 'Languages',               name: 'languages'},
{title: 'Education',               name: 'education'},
{title: 'Featured Skills',         name: 'skills'},
{title: 'Certificates',            name: 'certificates'},
{title: 'Experience',              name: 'experience'},  
...];
```

Each section should contain a different form with selects, inputs, datepickers, draggable items, chips etc. But in the same time it should be a **one large form** that will be published to the server.

Since it's a pretty big amount of form elements and they are separated visually in my layout, it would be wise to split them to components.
But I cannot find any examples online of how to achieve that.

Here is how my main component looks like:

```
// profile.component.html
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(profileForm)"> 
  <div id="{{section.name}}" *ngFor="let section of formSections">
    <div class="editprofile-title">{{section.title}}</div>
    <div class="editprofile-form" >
      <div *ngIf="section.name=='general'"
           [group]="profileForm"
           profileGeneralFormComp ></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='financial'"
           profileFinancialFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='languages'"
           profileLanguagesFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='education'"
           profileEducationFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='skills'"
           profileSkillsFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='certificates'"
           profileCertificatesFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='experience'"
           profileExperienceFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

      <div *ngIf="section.name=='links'"
           profileLinksFormComp
           [group]="profileForm"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Main struggle is that i can't pass a parent formGroup to my component and fill it with formControls inside.

Any help/advice will be appreciated.

Comment: A solution can be using [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)